# partially string token replacement in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, converters

I am trying to create a router for a framework of my own, let suppose i have a route registered like this

```
$f->addRoute("/note/$1/edit/$2", "/note/edit/$1");
```

and what this tells to router is that for given string like `/note/2/edit/some/non/sense/url` convert to `/note/edit/2` how can i do this!?

I have been working on this for hours but i couldn't find any regex to doing so!!

I would appreciate any help here.

Comment: How could we know anything about your own router structure? In general, special cases should be stored somewhere and specify exception route rules for some router (it can be config/DB or even directly passed array)

Comment: I believe there is no need to know about my router structure! all i am asking is how to convert a string like "/note/$1/edit/$2" to "/note/edit/$1" which is a structure free question and for knowing about my router structure see https://github.com/dariushha/zinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('|^/note/(\d+)/edit/.*$|', '/note/edit/$1', '/note/2/edit/some/non/sense/url');
```

Basically, you have to be careful about a few things:

- You don't want to use '/' as your regex delimiter unless you want to escape every '/' in your regex, so I've used '|' above
- I've used \d+ which implies 'any digit', if you have non-digit values here, you may want to use [^/]+ which means 'anything that isn't a forward slash'